# php ldap bind warning

Tags: php, codeigniter, ldap, warnings

Does it possible anyhow to avoid php warning on the screen when are invalid credentials on ldap_bind, but without use @ldap_bind or error_reporting set to 0?

I tried with:

```
               try {
                    if(!ldap_bind($ds, $binddn, $password)) {

                        throw new Exception('Invalid credentials');
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    var_dump($e->getMessage());
                }
```

But it doesn't work. PHP warning is still on the screen.

Does anyone know solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/de/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

It's nothing to do with the ldap-extension but with your php-settings. You should use the `log_errors`-directive in php.ini to log errors to an error-log.

And as the ldap-extension currently doesn't throw exceptions you will not have much luck with wrapping the `ldap_bind` into a `try-catch`-Block. You can though add a custom error-handler right before the call to any of the ldap-functions and replace that one with the default-error-handler.

For that have a look at http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-error-handler.php and https://github.com/zendframework/zend-ldap/blob/master/src/Ldap.php#L825-L827